# Command line showing nothing no output

Tags: powershell, security

I have been studying privilege escalation on windows and came across some powershell script that look up vulnderabilties.

When i run these ( multiple scripts) I get no output while the documentation i find on them and video's all show output. Unless I specifically tell it to output it to a file,

This makes me think it has something to do with my system. I am running windows 7 64-bit on a local standard user.

[image]

For example i used:
https://github.com/rasta-mouse/Sherlock

and:

https://github.com/PowerShellEmpire/PowerTools/tree/master/PowerUp

Comment: This will be hard or impossible to answer without seeing the script(s)

Comment: ditto, and also the second link clearly shows it is [Depreciated](https://github.com/PowerShellEmpire/PowerTools/tree/master/PowerUp#powertools-is-now-depreciated)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to check if your current user has changed to Administrator ?Maybe there is a GPO or theses privileges esclations are not working for your version